# How to test SafeHandle?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, native-code

I Have the following class:

```
 internal class House
 {
  public SafeHouse SafeHouseHandler { get; private set; }

   internal House()
    {
        IntPtr nativP = NativeMethods.UnitType();
        SafeHouseHandler = new SafeHouse(nativP);
    }
}
```

And:

```
    public class SafeHouse : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
     public SafeHouse(IntPtr ownsHandle)
        : base(true)
    {
        SetHandle(ownsHandle);
    }

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        NativeMeth.Delete(handle);
        return true;
    }
  }
```

I want to write a test that make sure that`ReleaseHandle` is called:

Test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SafeHouseTest()
    {
        var house = new House();
        SafeHouse safeHouse = house.SafeHouseHandler;

        Assert.AreNotEqual(IntPtr.Zero, safeHouse.DangerousGetHandle());

        house = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Assert.AreEqual(IntPtr.Zero, safeHouse.DangerousGetHandle());
    }
```

result:

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<0>. Actual:<489437772>.
```

Why is `safeHouse`not returning `0` when `house = null`?
If my approach to test is wrong, any suggestion to test such a class will be appreciated.

Comment: `safeHouse` is not `null` so `SafeHouse` is not collected by GC since you are still using it. Also I do not see why `DangerousGetHandle()` should return `IntPtr.Zero` after `ReleaseHandle()` called.

Comment: Well, test failed.  You assume that SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid sets the handle back to null.  Note the ambiguity in the name, should it be reset to zero or -1?  As you found out it just doesn't.  Consider testing safeHandle.IsValid instead.  Or call base.SetHandle(IntPtr.Zero) in your ReleaseHandle() override.

Comment: @HansPassant Great suggestion. However I think my approach is totally wrong. How can i write a test that verify `NativeMeth.Delete(handle)` is called when `House` object is no longer in use?